# How to run tmux inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, tmux

I have some docker container running on a P2 instance.
In the past I run tmux in the P2 instance a run a docker container inside.
Afterwards I used

```
docker exec -it
```

to get into the running docker container.
I would like to avoid the above and be able to run tmux inside an existing container. hitting

```
tmux new -s <some name>
```

Doesn't do anything.

Comment: There's no way of getting _not_ using `docker exec` to get into a running container. Perhaps you'd like to explain _why_ do you want tmux and what is your endgoal out of this.

Comment: Do you just want to run the `tmux` server in the container, then connect to a session using a local `tmux` client?

Comment: @SathyajithBhat "There's no way of getting not using docker exec to get into a running container" - that's incorrect. You can ssh into it. See moebius' answer.

Answer (score 6):

I assume that you want to connect to a docker container running remotely via `tmux`. In order to do this, you will have to run an ssh server within the container and attach to the `tmux` session using `ssh`. For example:

- Create the container image with `ssh` and `tmux` installed. The `Dockerfile` might look like this:

  ```
  FROM ubuntu:latest
  RUN apt-get update && \
    apt install -y tmux && \
    apt install -y openssh-server && \
    service ssh start && \
    tmux new -s mysesh
  EXPOSE 22/tcp
  ```
- Run the container, and port forward the ssh port:

  ```
  docker run -it -d -p 8654:22 <image name>
  ```
- Attach to the `tmux` session:

  ```
  ssh user@<hostname> -p 8654 -t "tmux a -t mysesh"
  ```

**Note**: `tmux` sessions are user specific, so ensure that the user exists in the container, and that the `tmux` session is started as the user within the container.

Comment: You should be able to expose the `tmux` server socket via a volume instead of running an `ssh` instance.

Comment: @chepner, thats a great suggestion - however I had difficulty getting it to work myself. From a quick look it seems like this might not be trivial (https://superuser.com/questions/358943/is-sharing-a-tmux-sockets-between-hosts-possible). Have you been able to get it working?

Comment: Ah, not yet. I didn't have much time to play with it, and what little time I did spend was on fumbling with Docker itself.

Answer (score 4):

If `tmux` is already running in the container, it's as simple as `docker attach container_name`.  ([Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/).)

Comment: How would it know if attach to tmux or other processes?

Comment: This should be the correct answer (in terms of best practices); upvoted

Answer (score 1):

tmux might not be available in docker image, you can install it once you're attached to the docker container.

```
sudo apt install tmux
```

Then you should be able to execute

```
tmux new -s <some name>
```

Tried this on a P3 machine worked fine.
Reference: https://linuxize.com/post/getting-started-with-tmux/